# Is there any react js open source calendar or scheduler to display the scheduled events

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar, scheduler

I need to display the events in calendar with day, week and month view(like microsoft Teams Calendar) as shown in below image.This task has to be done using react.js. I have never worked with calendars, so I am confused about whether I should build the interface from scratch or use open-source calendar libraries. If there are any tutorials or open-source libraries that can help me get this task done, please let me know because I haven't been finding anything helpful.

[please find attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAg6d.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Material UI has a pretty good Calendar component, check it out on their website.